# Voltage follower circuit gives a square wave rarther than a sine wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, non-inverting

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD8fxp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have created my voltage follower circuit as shown above. But when I connect an oscilloscope, it shows me a square wave at the output instead of a sine wave . Why would this happen?

Comment: Your buffer configuration is wrong. Non-inverting input should be connected to the incoming signal, and inverting input should be connected to the output. One more thing: Don't expect the output to swing up and down to supply level if you're not using a R2R (rail-to-rail) opamp. In your circuit, the input level is 10Vpp and supply is ±5V, so the output will be clipped.

Comment: Please also have a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: @RohatKılıç

"if you're not using a R2R (rail-to-rail) opamp"

What do you mean by R2R opamp?

Comment: @Taven "Rail" indicates a supply rail (positive or negative). Rail-to-rail opamps can swing their outputs down to negative supply rail (-5V in your case) and up to positive supply rail (+5V in your case). Other non-R2R opamps can swing lower (e.g. +/-4.5V instead of +/-5V. Check datasheet).

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't have negative feedback: inverting input should be connected to the output. Compare your schematic with [a proper voltage follower](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-amp-follower.html). Without negative feedback, your amplifier gain is *very large*, so even small signals get amplified to levels far beyond the maximum output level.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that

1) I had connected the ground terminal to the inverting terminal

2) I had not connected the negative terminal of the 12V ac source and the negative terminal of the 5V DC source. There should be a common ground between them.